# Im trying to figure out how to make a button toggle in react, but Im getting no errors pop up. Whats the deal?

Tags: reactjs

Looking at a simple to-do app, but the toggle button isnt handling the style of marking a todo complete after clicking the button handler. Im not getting any errors, but may have overlooked something simple.

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Addtodo from "./components/Addtodo";
import Todos from "./components/Todos";
import {Provider} from "./context"

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider>
    <div className="app-container">
      <Header></Header>
      <Addtodo></Addtodo>
      <Todos></Todos>
    </div>
    </Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here are the components.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Addtodo extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <form>
                <input type="text" className="form-control rounded-0" placeholder="Write down a task"/>

            <button className="form-control rounded-0 btn-secondary" type="submit">Add a task</button>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

---

```
import React from 'react'

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <div className="card bg-info text-center text-light rounded-0">
            <h1 className="display-4">
                <i className="fas fa-clipboard-list mr-3"></i> <span className="text-dark mr-3">MERN</span> Task Master!
            </h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Consumer } from "../context"

export default class Todo extends Component {
    style = () => {
    const { complete } = this.props.todo
    return { textDecoration: complete ? "line-through" : "none" }
    }
    toggle = (id, dispatch) => {
        dispatch({ type: "TOGGLE", payload: id })
    }
    render() {
        const { title, id } = this.props.todo
        return (
            <Consumer>{value =>{
            const { dispatch } = value
            return <h3 className="text-dark text-center p-1 bg-light border-bottom" style=
            {this.style()}>
                <i className="far fa-times-circle fa-sm float-left m-1 text-danger"></i>{title}
                <input type="checkbox" className="m-2 float-right" onChange={this.toggle.bind(this,
                    id, dispatch)} />
            </h3>
             }}</Consumer>

        )
    }
}
```

---

```
import Todo from "./Todo";
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {Consumer} from "../context"

//import consumer which holds the value of the state
//for each todo we are just returning one by passing props
export default class Todos extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Consumer>{value =>{
                const {todos} = value
                return todos.map(t=><Todo todo={t} key={t.id}></Todo>)
            }}</Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

Does anyone have a solution to why this isnt working? Im struggling a bit. An example should help if possible.

Answer (score 0):

So for starters your not doing anything with the button. You are not handling the click in any of the components.

Second your not connecting the data from the store using the "connect" function.

To be honest it seems you are missing a good bit of stuff but you can see an example of how to create the todo app using React Redux on the the React Redux website [here](https://react-redux.js.org/introduction/basic-tutorial).

Hope this helps.